# How to keep a long-running process run with Kerberos and Andrew file system?

Tags: kerberos, afs

I am running a bash script on a Scientific Linux server. The script has a loop for copying files and running some programs. The process for running the script probably takes a day or two. But I always can't finish running the script, because of the following error:

> cp: cannot open `somefile' for reading: Permission denied

I suspect that the cause is due to Kerberos and/or Andrew file system on the server.

How can I make my long-running script run well to finish?
Thanks.

Comment: Contact your cluster administrator. Again.

Comment: I can't. So I ask here.

Comment: will i have more luck on unix.se?

Comment: If you insist on not talking to the right people, then that would certainly be better than here.

Comment: [sf] is not intended for end-user support.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724902/how-does-one-send-new-commands-to-run-to-an-already-running-nohup-process-or-run

Answer (score 1):

You should use [kstart](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/k5start.html) (which is packaged in [EPEL](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/kstart) for Scientific Linux) to run your process.  It will keep refreshing your Kerberos ticket, as well as run aklog if you use -t.

Comment: do you know if your suggestions works for this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724902/how-does-one-send-new-commands-to-run-to-an-already-running-nohup-process-or-run ?